# Java 8 DateTime check if period contains specific day

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time

I want to check if a period of to dates contain the 29th of February.

```
private static final MonthDay LEAP = MonthDay.of(Month.FEBRUARY, 29);
```

i tried:

```
if (LEAP.isAfter(beginDate) && LEAP.isBefore(maturity)) {

    }
```

but `beginDate` and `maturity` are from the type `LocalDate`
so the methods `.isAfter` and `.isBefore` can't be used.

**Example**

`beginDate` is 15.01.2012
`maturity` is 20.01.2013

during this period the 29th of February exists

**Solution**

I have finally found a solution:

```
for (int i = beginDate.getYear(); i <= maturity.getYear(); i++) {
    final Year year = Year.of(i);
    if (year.isLeap()) {
        if (beginDate.compareTo(LEAP.atYear(i)) <= 0 || maturity.compareTo(LEAP.atYear(i)) >= 0) {
            minMaturity.plusDays(1);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Just check the last date of feb month

Comment: Is it a joda time or java 8 time api question? The answer may be different...

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to create a `TemporalAdjuster` that returns the next 29th February and check if `maturity` is before or after that date. Example (not tested):

```
public static TemporalAdjuster nextOrSame29Feb() {
  return temporal -> {
    LocalDate input = LocalDate.from(temporal);
    if (input.isLeapYear()) {
      LocalDate feb29 = input.with(MonthDay.of(FEBRUARY, 29));
      if (!input.isAfter(feb29)) return feb29;
    }
    for (int year = input.getYear() + 1; ; year++) {
      if (Year.isLeap(year)) return LocalDate.of(year, FEBRUARY, 29);
    }
  };
}
```

And your code becomes:

```
boolean contains29Feb = !maturity.isBefore(beginDate.with(nextOrSame29Feb()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried converting the `LocalDate` and `MonthDay` to `DateTime` using [toDateTimeAtStartOfDay](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateTimeAtStartOfDay()) and [toDateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/base/AbstractPartial.html#toDateTime(org.joda.time.ReadableInstant)) respectively?

You need to test if this would result in true when the year is not a leap year. It might.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an Interval and check that? Something like:

```
    LocalDate beginDate, maturity;
    final Interval interval = new Interval(beginDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(), maturity.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay());
    if (interval.contains(new DateTime(beginDate.getYear(), Month.FEBRUARY, 29, 0, 1)) ||
        interval.contains(new DateTime(maturity.getYear(), Month.FEBRUARY, 29, 0, 1))) {
        // It does
    }
```

Comment: it will fail when the 29th of February is in the maturity year

Comment: True, and to check both is ugly. :-/

Answer (score 1):

I like to think in terms of test cases. What values for `beginDate` and `endDate` will cause such a method to return true or false?

For example, what if they are in the same year? Perhaps both values are on the same side of Feb 29, or they span it.

What if they're in different years? What if those years are adjacent, or if there are other years in between? Perhaps none of the intervening years are even leap years.

What you can then do in this sort of scenario is put together examples of these cases and then write a method, adjusting it until all the asserts pass.

Below is an approach you could take. You may want to add cases where `beginDate` and/or `maturity` land on a leap day.

```
public class Q26403911 {
    @Test
    public void testContainsLeapYear() throws Exception {
        Assert.assertTrue(isContainsLeapYear(LocalDate.of(1984, 2, 28), LocalDate.of(1984, 3, 1)));
        Assert.assertFalse(isContainsLeapYear(LocalDate.of(1985, 2, 28), LocalDate.of(1985, 3, 1)));
        Assert.assertFalse(isContainsLeapYear(LocalDate.of(1984, 2, 27), LocalDate.of(1984, 2, 28)));
        Assert.assertFalse(isContainsLeapYear(LocalDate.of(1984, 3, 1), LocalDate.of(1984, 3, 2)));
        Assert.assertTrue(isContainsLeapYear(LocalDate.of(1984, 2, 28), LocalDate.of(1985, 3, 1)));
        Assert.assertTrue(isContainsLeapYear(LocalDate.of(1983, 3, 1), LocalDate.of(1984, 3, 1)));
        Assert.assertFalse(isContainsLeapYear(LocalDate.of(1984, 3, 1), LocalDate.of(1985, 3, 1)));
        Assert.assertFalse(isContainsLeapYear(LocalDate.of(1983, 2, 28), LocalDate.of(1984, 2, 28)));
        Assert.assertTrue(isContainsLeapYear(LocalDate.of(1983, 3, 1), LocalDate.of(1985, 2, 28)));
        Assert.assertFalse(isContainsLeapYear(LocalDate.of(1985, 3, 1), LocalDate.of(1987, 2, 28)));
    }

    public boolean isContainsLeapYear(LocalDate beginDate, LocalDate maturity) {
        if (beginDate.getYear() == maturity.getYear())
        {
            if (!Year.isLeap(beginDate.getYear()))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (maturity.isBefore(LocalDate.of(beginDate.getYear(), Month.FEBRUARY, 29)))
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (beginDate.isAfter(LocalDate.of(maturity.getYear(), Month.FEBRUARY, 29)))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
        else if (Year.isLeap(beginDate.getYear())
                        && !beginDate.isAfter(LocalDate.of(beginDate.getYear(), Month.FEBRUARY, 29)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (Year.isLeap(maturity.getYear())
                        && !maturity.isBefore(LocalDate.of(maturity.getYear(), Month.FEBRUARY, 29)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            for (int year = beginDate.getYear() + 1; year < maturity.getYear(); year++)
            {
                if (Year.isLeap(year))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can propose you next solution, witout `MonthDay`

```
   static int LEAP = 31 + 29;  

   public static boolean conatins29Feb(LocalDate dateFrom, LocalDate dateTo)  
   {
      final int yearFrom = dateFrom.getYear(),
              yearTo = dateTo.getYear(),
              dayOfYearFrom = dateFrom.getDayOfYear(),
              dayOfYearTo = dateTo.getDayOfYear(),
              nearestLeapYear = (yearTo / 4) * 4; // nearest to `dateTo`

      return (yearFrom <= nearestLeapYear && yearTo >= nearestLeapYear)
              && (yearFrom < nearestLeapYear || dayOfYearFrom <= LEAP) 
                  && (yearTo > nearestLeapYear || dayOfYearTo >= LEAP);
   }
```

Comment: Are you sure about: `nearestLeapYear = (yearTo / 4) * 4;`? 1900 was not a leap year for example... Using the built in methods is probably a better bet than doing it manually...